# Css tooltip content from another div

Tags: css, tooltip

I have a css tooltip which is triggered by hovering over a link, the tooltip text is then populated from the span element hidden in the link text.

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/70wxxhne/

However I now need to have other html elements within the popup so ideally I would like to load the tooltip content from another div (note1 in the fiddle), is this possible with css alone?

```
<--css-->
.ktooltip {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.ktooltip .ktooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
background: #fff;
width: 150px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 5px 5px;
top: -5px;
left: 105%;
border:2px solid grey;

/* Position the tooltip */
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}

.ktooltip:hover .ktooltiptext {
visibility: visible;
}

<p>Here is some text with a note here
<sup class="ref">
    <a href="#note1" id="note1" class="ktooltip">Tooltip
        <span class="ktooltiptext">Current Tooltip text</span>
    </a>
</sup>
that continues on here too.
</p>

<div id="note1" class="ktooltip2"><p>wannabe <b>tooltip</b> with a<a 
href="link">link</a></p></div>
```

Comment: you want to show the tooltip on the "tooltip"  link when you hover over the "link" link? if not can you clarify exactly what you're wanting to hover, and where you want a tooltip to display?

Comment: That is not possible without script since the `#note1` element is neither a child nor sibling to the element with the `hover`. Why do you need to move it outside the existing markup?

Comment: I want the content in div note1 to pop up when i hover over 'Tooltip' rather than the content in the span element like it currently does.

I want to move it outside of the link text because I need full html formatting which should not really go into a href element.

Hope thats clear.

Comment: As of HTML5, you can use block elements, i.e. `div`, inside an anchor, so no worries about not getting that validated properly anymore, so simply replace your span with your div. If your div contain a link, you need to wrap them both (nested links is not valid) and make the div a sibling

Comment: Anyway, it can be outside the anchor, but inside the sup, so it is  a sibling

Comment: Paul (and @vals ) Here is a sample, will this be an option? https://jsfiddle.net/70wxxhne/2/

Comment: Great, this seems to work well. I had found an example that popped up a div at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_hover2 but as soon as I wrapped my link in the sup element it stopped working. Either way, the above is a much easier solution. Cheers

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I did, and posted, with your existing code...and with mine, you will be able to actually click the link inside the popup, you won't with the linked w3school's sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of HTML5, you can use block elements, i.e. `div`, inside an anchor, so no worries about not getting that validated properly anymore, so simply replace your `span` with your `div`.

If your `div` contains a link/anchor, you need to wrap them both (nested links is not valid) and make the `div` a sibling, here done with the existing `ref`

*Note, to also be able to actually click on the link in the tooltip, I changed its left position to 99%, so it does not disappear when hovering the tooltip itself.*

```css
.ref {
  position: relative;
}
.ktooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}
.ref .ktooltip2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 99%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ref:hover .ktooltip2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>Here is some text with a note here
  <sup class="ref">
   <a href="#note1" id="note1" class="ktooltip">Tooltip</a>
    <div id="note1" class="ktooltip2">
      <p>wannabe <b>tooltip</b> with a<a href="link">link</a></p>
    </div>
  </sup> that continues on here too.
</div>
```

Comment: Exact! Great answer

Comment: Yeah great work, I have accepted the answer. Thanks for helping me through this.